# How to remove around elements shadow of dragging item

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, drag-and-drop, vuetify.js

I am trying to drag and drop item into another section ,
when I start drag , it displays around elements shadow ,
how can I avoid displaying that shadow ?

as you see in below picture , when one of red tags were dragged , it displays other tags shadow also that not desirable for me.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

check your button active class style. i think this effect applied by ::before or ::after selectors.

try this:

```
button:active::before {
  content: "" !important;
}

button:active::after{
   content: "" !important;
}
```